# JS Push element to array if it does not exist, then re-evaluate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, iteration

I'm using the following.

```
const employeesByDepartment = {};

employeesArray.forEach((employee) => {

    if (!(employeesByDepartment[employee.department])) {
        employeesByDepartment[employee.department] = {};
        employeesByDepartment[employee.department].managers = [];
        employeesByDepartment[employee.department].members = [];
    }

    let thisManagerAlreadyAdded = false;

    // PROBLEM ON NEXT LINE
    employeesByDepartment[employee.department].managers.forEach((manager) => {
        if (manager.id === employee.manager) {
            thisManagerAlreadyAdded = true;
        }
    });

    if (thisManagerAlreadyAdded === false) {
        employeesByDepartment[employee.department].managers
            .push(ReturnOneUser(employee.manager));
    }
});
```

Problem: No manager is ever found to be in the array, so they're all added. That is, expressions inside this block are never reached.

```
employeesByDepartment[employee.department].managers.forEach((manager)
```

In my testing, that array always has `length` of `0`. Therefore, I'm assuming the JS interpreter (Node.js) doesn't re-examine the array every time this the `forEach` gets executed. So far, I've also tried the array indexOf method and a for loop, but no managers are ever found in the array.

So, how can I add a manager that isn't found and then re-evaluate the array for the next manager?

Comment: can you add a dummy employeesArray?

Comment: `foreach` is not a valid Javascript array function. Capitalization matters.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, yes, of course. Thank you. Example updated to include your correction.

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher, wouldn't that just move the problem to a different array?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have solved this exact same problem many times. Let me add an answer.

Comment: There's no `.any` in js @CertainPerformance, it's `some`, `filter` or `find`

Comment: there is `.find` and `.some` :D

Comment: There is a problem in the design. As @Melchia already answered. Again, Can you share a dummy data and an expected result data?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't moving the condition solve your problem?

```
const employeesByDepartment = {};

employeesArray.forEach((employee) => {
  let thisManagerAlreadyAdded = false;
    if (!(employeesByDepartment[employee.department])) {
        employeesByDepartment[employee.department] = {};
        employeesByDepartment[employee.department].managers = [];
        employeesByDepartment[employee.department].members = [];
    }

  if (!thisManagerAlreadyAdded) {
        employeesByDepartment[employee.department].managers
            .push(ReturnOneUser(employee.manager));
    }

    // MOVE IT HERE
    employeesByDepartment[employee.department].managers.forEach((manager) => {
        if (manager.id === employee.manager) {
            thisManagerAlreadyAdded = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .find to check if the user already exists in certain array.

ie, If `managers` is the current array, then using `.find` will always go thru the whole array again and check for result. That is considering both `manager.id` and `employee.manager` is string.

```
!!managers.find(manager => manager.id === employee.manager);
```

If you use `!!` at the start, it will return a boolean value. You won't need to use any of the `thisManagerAlreadyAdded` style code.

So you can simply use this,

```
const managers = employeesByDepartment[employee.department].managers;
const thisManagerAlreadyAdded = !!managers.find(manager => manager.id === employee.manager);
if (!thisManagerAlreadyAdded) {
    managers.push(ReturnOneUser(employee.manager));
}
```